# Getting empty params, query, and body from axios api call (been stuck on for 3 days, Note: just for learning as new to mern stack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, parameters, axios

For some reason it only comes as empty json like:{} (as seen in the output)

I would like if instead I could access the parameters sent from the routes somehow.

Frontend:

```
let api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/validateSignIn",
})

let config = {
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    } 
}

// api.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; 

export default function TopBar(input){

    function postCredentials(un, pw){
        let params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('username', un);
        params.append('password', pw);
        let getResponse =  api.get('/', params, config)
        .then(response=>{
          return (response.data)
        }).catch()
        return getResponse
      }

    async function validateSignIn(){
        let user = document.getElementById("username").value
        let success = await(postCredentials(user, document.getElementById("password").value))
        console.log(success)
        if(success){
            input.setState({"name":user})
            return input.setSignedIn(true);
        }
        else{
            console.log("invalid login attempt")
        }
    }
    return(
        <div className="signInPage">
            <div>Enter UserName: </div>
            <input type="username" id="username" maxLength="32" autoComplete="off">                
            </input>
            <div>Enter Password: </div>
            <input type="password" id="password" maxLength="32" autoComplete="off">                
            </input>
            <br />
            <button onClick={() => validateSignIn()}>Click to sign in</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Server:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

app.all("/", function(req, res, next) {
    req.header("Origin", "http://localhost:3000/");
    return next();
});

app.use('/login', loginRoutes)
app.use('/validateSignIn', SignInRoutes)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
```

Route:

```
const router = express.Router();

export const getSignin = (req, res) => { 
    console.log("params:" + JSON.stringify(req.params))
    console.log("query:" + JSON.stringify(req.query))
    console.log("body:" + JSON.stringify(req.body))

    if(!req.username)
        res.send(false)
    else{res.send(true)}
}
```

Output:

```
{
params:{}
query:{}
body:{}
}
```

Note: The desired output I'm trying for would contain the username and password sent from front end somewhere reachable. I don't mind if it is body, query, params, or somewhere else.

Comment: I'm bad at front end, but what if you change the www-form-urlencoded to json?

Comment: Sadly didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the answer was that you can't send information in the body when using a GET request, but it works when doing a POST request. Found out after reading API documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api

Comment: Yeah, when you use `axios.create()` the default method is GET, but the params and query for sure works in GET requests. Imo using `axios.post()` or other method is much simpler